# Multi-threading lowering speed?

Tags: multithreading, performance

I am editing a multi-threaded application so am having to learn it and have a theory question.

Having a second thread allows the application to continue functioning when the main thread would be waiting for resources to become available so it it supposed speed up the application if done properly this I get.

What I was thinking was that there is only so much wasted processing time in a single thread application so if you have a lot of threads then each one would have to wait for a turn to process resulting in a slower program all together.

Have I got this wrong ?

If not what is a recommended economical number of threads.

Comment: Depends on your certain task. Threads are stopped and started in the middle of a function so using them may impose big sync overhead. Also, there are other ways of processing things parallel (e.g. process 10K textfiles), like coroutines, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine

Comment: Plenty of Wikipedia links already, the important one is Amdahl's law.  And no, 70 threads doesn't make a dbase engine faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a matter of waste. And multiple threads isn't always the right solution.

If you have a single threaded code that is designed to be sequential (Each line of code needs the previous line of code to be processed) then there is no point in separating it into different threads.

Multithreading is only good when you can open up threads and not freeze one-another with joins (when you don't have to really wait for other threads to finish).

Another thing you need to take into account is that a single thread runs in a single processor. So, if you have a long calculation (like matrix multiplication) you can divide chunks into different processors on a multi-processor machine.

So, about how many ? It depends on what you're doing.

If you are just doing an asynchronous method, where you just want it to run and return a value when it's finished, then there's no limit for the number of threads. You can use how many you find right logically (Although there is an overhead for too many threads)

If you want to break-up a calculation and send different chunks to different processors, there's no reason to open more threads then the number of processors. (although I find that in some cases if you use about 1.5 the number of processors you can get better results)

Comment: I've got about 60-70 threads gathering data from different places and moving it to a central database. the tasks are independent of one another but it is only a dual core machine. must stress not my code, I am trying to work out why it is slow.

Comment: if it's gathering to a single database, there must be some kind of lock on that database. If the lock is placed in a high level, then it will block the database for too long.

Comment: You should consider checking if you can use a read-write lock there, or keep buffered data

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here :

[Wiki is your friend ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28computer_architecture%29)

----- Edited -----

Threads are just there to do a better usage of you CPU, so they are not supposed to speed up you application.

Formerly, in my multhreaded applications I created my own pool of thread in fact 2-5 by core. Now I use the pool managed by the system API and it can be up to 30.

My advice, built the tasks you want to run in parallel on the top of asynchronous API, and spent some time to build the graph of calls. So that each task can be given to any thread. Doing this way, let the system give you the next available thread.

Another advice, reduce in your thread the number of time you call APIs getting into the kernel.

In your case you have to find the bottleneck, disk, network.

Comment: I have read that and it does not answer my question, in fact it was an article similar to this that spawned the question.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think you are more interested in the theory behind parallel computing, not so much multi-threading: [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing).

The short answer is that it depends a lot on how parallelizable the work actually is, how many processors are working on it, and how many data dependencies there are between the parallelized parts.